# How to retrieve a payment method on the client side?

Tags: c#, angular, stripe-payments

We are running an App with a Angular/Typescript frontend and a .NET backend, using Stripe Elements and Stripe.NET respectively.

#### We are currently using the "Sources" API.

The frontend can create sources, the backend saves them to our specific users. When you open the frontend again, the backend sends a list of source ids. The frontend then collects the data it needs to display those sources directly from Stripe so the user can pick one of his saved sources to pay and does not have to enter all the data again.

#### Enter the Payment Method / Payment Intend API.

Due to EU regulations Stripe has a new API that requires us to create cards no longer as "source" but as a "PaymentMethod". So I implemented that in the backend, opened the frontend in my IDE, updated the @types/stripe-v3 package and found the new payment intent API.

The only thing missing: I cannot figure out how the frontend is to access the payment method data, once created. I can create it. Send it to the backend. The backend can retrieve it. Send back the ID to the frontend... and now what? How to display the payment methods available?

I had expected a `stripe.retrievePaymentMethod()` as there is a  `stripe.retrieveSource()`. But no such luck.

The only option I currently see to present the user with a list of existing payment methods is getting this info on the backend and piping it all, class by class, property by property to the client. Basically copying every single data class stripe has into our own backend REST definition. That cannot be right.

What am I missing? Why is there no `stripe.retrievePaymentMethod()` on the frontend? Did I not understand some fundamental facts about what those APIs should do?

Comment: Are you using mobile payment or payment gateway or maybe something else?

Comment: @SaeidAmini I'm not sure how to answer that question. I'm using Stripe, specifically their Payment Method API. The frontend application will be available on both mobile and web. Are you talking about other Stripe APIs or functionality?

Comment: No, I mean there are many payment gateway types. Mobile pay, credit card, and bank card. I wanted to know which one you are using.

Comment: @SaeidAmini We are supporting SEPA and Credit cards in our application, but only credit cards are supported by the Payment Method API right now, so my problem right now is with credit cards.

Comment: correct me if im wrong, I've used the stripe api for EU payments before, but since you are saving paymentmethods I assume you are using their vault and with that you get a customerid, each customer id is associated to a payment method so why cant you get payment methods from your vault using customerid

Comment: You wouldnt be able to save the payment methods without the customer id in any case so you definitely should be saving that id to your database  or a ref to that at the very least (unless you are not using your own user db and instead are relying on stripe as a user base which wouldn't be the best option)

Comment: after that its simply using the paymentsapi method to lis pm_ids by customer               https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/list

Comment: @Pari I can do that on the backend. With Sources, I was able to send the IDs to the frontend and get the display data from stripe.js. That is no longer possible with their new PaymentMethod API and that's what I'm asking here. I don't have the user id in the frontend, because it wasn't neccessary up to now.

Comment: Matter of fact, listing payment methods is a backend method *only*, so even as a workaround, it would not work for me.

Comment: Well retrieving them is a backend operation, getting them to display for the user is not. But I see you already answered the question.

Comment: @PariBaker "getting them to display for the user is not" how is it not? The frontend API call to do just that does not longer exist?

Comment: Well I mean you said you couldnt use it as a workaround solution, but you could. Since the frontend API would be making the calls to the backend. So the frontend wouldn't have to call anything from stripe directly. Your frontend would call the PaymentsApi backend to list the current user's payment options (assuming you can go back now and add the customer_id) and that would be returned to the frontend. Then the frontend would submit the payment through your backend.

Comment: @PariBaker Sure. Sorry, maybe that's a miscommunication on my part. I don't consider that a "workaround" because it's already my worstcase scenario. A workable workaround would have been to do something on the frontend side only without changing the backend.

Comment: I would say switch to Braintree, but their support for Angular is not that great, and they don't have IBAN

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After contacting Stripe directly, it was confirmed that that's just the way it is:

> I think it's just an oversight that we didn't add one.
>
> There are similar functions in the mobile SDK so I don't see why we shouldn't have it

There are no immediate plans to add the functionality back in in the very near future,
so as a workaround, I will tunnel all the data through our backend(s).

Comment: This is still the case, confirmed today with Stripe support.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand as well, I think your problem is following and the sequence of that. I hope this helps you.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed flow diagram. The thing is, I already got that flow working with their Sources API. Now due to European regulations I have to use their new Payment method API. I have that flow working with their new API as well, but one method is missing from that API. That is what my question is about. So I'm looking for an answer very specific to the vendor API I listed in my question: Stripe and their payment method API.

Comment: Based on my flow diagram, which step is missed?

Comment: I don't have a problem with the general flow. I need to know which *specific function* of the *specific API* will give me the credit card details to an existing token (for example brand and last four digits) so I can display them in the frontend. The old API could do that, but the new API is missing that method. When the user enters their data, I need to present a list of their current payment methods for them to pick one.

Comment: Yes, I do. They don't seem to have the method I'm looking for in their new API.

Comment: I implemented a lot of payment gateways and I'm familiar with a master card and visa card but, unfortunately I've had no experience with European payment gateways like Stripe but, I’m trying to help. Maybe this helps you: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/cards/reusing-cards

Comment: Yes, I have read that before I started. Don't get me wrong, I appreciate the help, but I think I need someone with good knowledge of the Stripe API, because that is what my question is about. Stripe itself is a US company btw. and *all* their credit card payments will use this new API, whether they happen in Europe or not.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a payment gateway like ccAvenue with DotNet and angular, in my case, I send the data to the server, and from the server, I tried to redirect to the payment gateway, but APIs return some result, and the result can not be redirected.

So I created a web-form with implementation, I redirected my app to web-forms page and from there I called the ccAvenue page, and in the response URL, I send the response page of webforms only and after saving the response I redirected to my angular app.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand, how that helps me with my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is workaround if you want to process 3Dsecure cards and still support other methods like SEPA.

You could attach both, confirmed `PaymentIntent` (payment method) or `Source` to the `Customer` object.
On your frontend you could implement both (StripeElements with client secret for 3Dsecure cards) and IBAN element for SEPA.

I could provide my code example how I save payment intent to the customer. It's in **PHP**, but for other languages logic should be the same.

Assuming that our client already confirmed PaymentIntent and we have it's id:

```
$intent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::retrieve($stripe_intent_id);
$payment_method = \Stripe\PaymentMethod::retrieve($intent->payment_method);
$stripe_customer = Stripe\Customer::create([
      'payment_method' => $intent->payment_method,
]);
```

In case you've already created Customer object before you could use attach method:

```
$payment_method->attach(['customer' => 'cus_FTkGe4lv5LfyI0']);
```

Then you'll be able to charge using `Customer` object `PaymentMethod` **or** `Source`;

I didn't try to attach both methods to the same customer object (we only allow customer to have one payment option at the same time), but it should work. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that suggestion, but I'm already doing that. The question was about whether the Payment Method API has a method called `retrievePaymentMethod`. I have no problems creating intents, attaching them to customers or doing the same with sources for SEPA payments.